# Is Javascript "caching" operations?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was implementing the Levenshtein distance function in Javascript, and I was wondering how much time it takes to run it with Wikedia's example ("sunday" & "saturday").

So I used `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` to determine the time spent for the function execution.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    console.time("benchmark" + i);
    var result = LevenshteinDistance("sunday", "saturday");
    console.timeEnd("benchmark" + i);
}
```

Since it was fluctuating between 0.4ms and 0.15ms, I used a loop and I stumbled upon weird values:

- 0.187ms
- 0.028ms
- 0.022ms
- 0.022ms
- 0.052ms
- 0.026ms
- 0.028ms
- 0.245ms
- 0.030ms
- 0.024ms
- 0.020ms
- 0.019ms
- 0.059ms
- 0.039ms
- 0.040ms

The recurring thing is the high value for the first (and rarely second) execution, then smaller values.
(Same behavior between JS in Chrome console and NodeJS.)

So my question is : Is Javascript "caching" executions (since JS is compiled with the V8 engine) ?

And also, can I use this behavior to make the function run faster when using different parameters each time ?

Comment: You're timing a very very small amount of work, and the differences are probably do to the runtime optimizing/compiling the code.

Comment: Probably, but 15 is not nearly enough runs to be sure.

Comment: I get that my case is not the best testing playground, but I was wondering if such a behavior was usual.

Comment: Side note - JavaScript is run in the V8 engine in Chrome, but other browsers (may) have other rendering engines which may not all follow the same behaviors at the lowest level.

Comment: @sphanley exactly, that's why I stated I used chrome & nodeJS (both use the V8 engine)

Comment: I can't comment on whether or not this is truely the case but ive seen similar symptoms when doing visualisations that went from 1 minute the first run down to 20-30s for subsequent runs.  Also using chrome but all client side.

Comment: @NickA that's really interesting. I'd really like to see a paper on that behavior (if it appears to be an intended feature). Did you run it in an environement using the V8 engine ?

Comment: @Seblor It was Chrome 52 on an isolated network where all work was done from the localhost but I couldn't tell you much more than that.  No node etc. Just a .js and .html file.

Comment: @NickA as far as I know, Chrome is using the V8, so I will test that behavior on firefox JS console to see if it works the same.

Comment: @NickA On firefox, each call takes around 0.3ms (a few times up to 0.45ms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

V8 is using a JIT compiler. It starts to compile everything as fast as it can with little optimizations because it wants to start quickly and then it optimizes the functions that are called multiple times to speed up the execution where it actually matters.

Why doesn't it optimize everything to begin with? To start faster. Some code is run only once and it would be a waste of time to optimize it because the time of running optimizations would be longer than the time saved by the optimizations. And JavaScript starts pretty quickly - compare running a Node.js hello world to compiling and running a Java hello world (yes, Node.js apps are compiled from scratch every time they start).

Consider this Node.js program, hello.js:

```
console.log('Hello from Node');
```

and this Java program, Hello.java:

```
class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("Hello from Java");
    }
}
```

Run the Node program:

```
$ time (node hello.js)
Hello from Node

real    0m0.059s
user    0m0.047s
sys 0m0.012s
```

and compare it with Java program:

```
$ time (javac Hello.java && java Hello)
Hello from Java

real    0m0.554s
user    0m1.073s
sys 0m0.068s
```

For more info see:

- http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/
- https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/07/digging-into-turbofan-jit.html
- http://jayconrod.com/posts/54/a-tour-of-v8-crankshaft-the-optimizing-compiler

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the links, I really appreciate it !