# Strange Regular Expression Method Behavior in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Faced such a problem. When you run the exec or match method, the first method call is always slower than the second. Subsequent calls - will be performed even faster.

```
0:       0.013281777024269104
1:       0.004966034680604935
2:       0.004561618596315384
3:       0.004366877138614654
4:       0.003996829882264137
5:       0.0037765540182590485
6:       0.00369636969268322
7:       0.003592779144644737
8:       0.0036278150379657746
9:       0.003481139928102493
10:      0.0035037004351615906
11:      0.004023797005414963
12:      0.003495175927877426
13:      0.0035397831946611404
14:      0.0034795581251382828
15:      0.0033910408914089203
16:      0.0033861002922058107
17:      0.0033773958384990693
18:      0.003347825139760971
19:      0.0034435260742902755
```

As far as I understand, the V8 engine somehow caches data. And at the next start of the method - this helps him to execute it faster. Only I can not understand the mechanism of such caching.

***Is it possible to expedite the first call? Provided that the function may receive random data.***

I wrote a small example below:

- inside the for loop, we get a random string with a fixed length;
- in a random line, in a random place the line for search is placed;
- iterations and loops are performed a specified number of times;
- the average value of the operating time is calculated: 0,1,2 ... calculation.

```js
// const { performance } = require('perf_hooks'); // comment out if this will run in the browser

const wordLength = 1000; // random string length
const searchString = `aBc123%!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]{}<>,./|*`; // used for regular expression and for substituting in a random string in a random place
let iterationCount = 100; // iterator start counter
const calculationsCount = 20; // number of calculations in one iteration
const timeOut = 30; // delay in ms between the iterator function call
const result = {};


const randomString = (length) => [...Array(length)].map(_ => (Math.random() * 36 | 0).toString(36)).join``;
const randomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
const regEscaping = (str) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');


const reg = new RegExp(regEscaping(searchString), "g");


const prepareResult = () => {
 for (let i = 0; i < calculationsCount; i++) {
  result[i] = [];
 }
}
prepareResult();


const iterator = () => {
 let tmp = result;

 for (let i = 0; i < calculationsCount; i++) {
  let text = randomString(wordLength);
  let position = randomNumber(wordLength);
  text = text.substr(0, position) + searchString + text.substr(position); // since the global key is used, random placement will not affect the result

  let start = performance.now();
  let result = text.match(reg);
  let end = performance.now();
  tmp[i].push(end - start);
 }

 iterationCount--;
 if (iterationCount) {
  setTimeout(iterator, timeOut);

 } else {
  for (let i = 0; i < calculationsCount; i++) {
   console.log(`${i}: \t ${tmp[i].reduce((a, b) => (a + b)) / tmp[i].length}`);
  }
 }
}
iterator();
```

Comment: Why does it matter to expedite the first call? Explain how this is a "problem". You've wasted more time writing this question than your program could ever hope to save in its lifetime with an expedited first call.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If I need to execute a regular expression 1 time, then there is no problem. But if I need to perform regular expression 10,000 times per second - there is a problem.

In my case - the faster I can recognize the incoming data (the first method call), the more efficiently my code can work.

Comment: Well, if the first call is about 3 time slower than each of the 9,999 others, the performance gain can be neglected

Comment: @Cid I am interested in the behavior of these methods. Why is the 1st method always slower than the 2nd; and the 2nd is slower than the 3rd; etc? Provided that the method always receives random data. And is there a way to make the "cache" remember from the first start of the method? In order to be able to reuse the "warmed" method in several functions at different times.
I’ll clarify, this problem is relevant for data up to 10-15k characters long.

Comment: I doubt you can speed up the first call. I'm sure V8 has done everything they can to optimize on their end, but the first call involves building a pattern matcher (I assume DFA) from the input string and returning the first match, so it's expected that it does a lot of extra work than subsequent calls, which work on the already-built, in-memory DFA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Javascript "caching" operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631226/is-javascript-caching-operations)